# creating lists based on JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I have this json array of dictionaries:

```
my_json == [
    { name: 'Allen', 'pass': 14, 'fail': 2 },
    { name: 'Meg', 'pass': 14, 'fail': 2 },
    { name: 'Catty', 'pass': 10, 'fail': 3 } 
]
```

I am using this data to create a highcharts bar chart with drilldown. 
I saw a fiddle demo and understand that my data series needs to be in the following format:

```
id:'pass'
data:[[Allen,14],[Meg,14],[Catty,10]
id:'fail'
data:[[Allen,2],[Meg,2],[Catty,3]
```

This looks like a list of lists and I'm absolutely clueless how to extract this sort of data
from the above JSON. My need is just this. I will just have two series: Pass/Fail. On drilling down, I get the names
of the children with their pass/fail ratio.

How to extract these lists from my JSON data?

Please let me know if you know any other easier way of drill charting this data with highcharts.
Here's the fiddle: [Chart fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/across-types/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function might help you to get the data you need to that format

```
function formatData (json) {
    var pass = {id: 'pass', data: []};
    var fail = {id : 'fail', data: []};
    for(var index in json) {
        pass.data.push([json[index].name, json[index].pass]);
        fail.data.push([json[index].name, json[index].fail]);
    }
    retrun [pass, fail];
}
```

Comment: On the beam! Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for.